# Xcode swift: How to add a share screen where you can share your own app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

I would like to add a share button to my Xcode project which, like for example by WhatsApp (if you press the share button there), displays a screen where you can share this app with a link to the AppStore (for example to share this app with your friends). Would this function also work if you have not yet published your app in the AppStore? Or do you have to publish the app first and then bring an update directly where this function has been added because otherwise, you won't get the app link?
How would that work?
I would be very happy to get help!
Warm greetings

[image]

Comment: Yes, If you have URL, you can share it.

Comment: Hey. thanks for your answer. So can I only integrate the sharing function into my app if I have already published it in the AppStore?

Comment: Yes you can. any file or url can be shared with this.

Comment: You can add a sharesheet at any point; the app doesn't have to have been published (as otherwise how would you develop and test it) .  Other than that I don't understand your question.  You would typically use the share sheet to share content related to the main view with others.  That content could be anything, including an app store url.

Comment: Hey @flanker. Thanks for your answer. Yes my question is whether I can find out how the link to my IOS app in the app store will be, before I publish it so that I can create the share function (with the link to my app in the app store) in my app **before** it is published.

Comment: I suppose you could pull it down from some backend at run time, or use a search url, but you'll not be able to embed a url in the code to something that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is by using firebase and dynamic links, its like getting your URL from apple but also being able to edit what page they see when they click on the link to go to your app.

if you go to the firebase website they have easy documentation and videos to set it up.